# base64 image php undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I have been searching for a base64 decoding error with this code:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '../../imagenes/articulos/');
$imgFinal = (isset($_POST['imagen']) ? $_POST['imagen'] : null);
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imgFinal);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

I've used the awesome cropper, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Andrew8xx8/awesome-cropper). That code above works fine in some photos, but in some others said `undefined index: imagen`

So, in some photos works, in another ones, don't... So, any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which images work? Which images don't? What the full error message and stack trace produced?

Comment: My guess is your $_POST var is not being set and is probably null. I don't see any code to deal with that situation. Try to echo it and find out. You can't decode a null value.

Comment: Add `print_r($_POST);` to your code and check, with many images, if the "imagen" item is being set.

Comment: Some images, I tried for many and I supossed may be the filesize or length of code, I don't know if is randomly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why some images goes null....

Comment: Well `print_r` sometimes throw the image base64 image, sometimes doesn't, samething with `var_dump()` may be string length? filesize?

Comment: Post your `<form>` code. Also, do notice that if `$imgFinal` is `null` the code will break. You can put that code block inside an `if` in order to decode only what is not `null`

Comment: Form code: `<form name="crear" action="index.php?crear=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="imagen" id="imagen" tabindex="1" width="150" test[image] />
</form>`
input type is hidden because a requirement of awesome cropper, if is not hidden, show the text box with base64 string.